# C++: unable to connect to server socket (linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, sigpipe

Dears,

I have a main program that executes a child process and tries to connect to this child process via socket. This connection works properly. But, when an error is detected, the main program tries to properly close the socket connection, then it kills the child process, restarts a new one, and tries to connect to new child.

The reconnection can work several hundreds of times. But, if I repeat this hundreds of time, after a certain number of cycles, my main program is no more able to connect to the child process.

I don't know it this has a link, but when trying to properly close socket, my main program sometimes receives a SIGPIPE. I ignore it and continue processing. But, I noticed that when the program does not accept anymore the connections, it always has received 10 SIGPIPES. I tried several times, and it always ends at 10.

Any idea ?

Regards,
Brice

EDITED :

Here is the code that closes the connection:
`

```
int BAE_nb_sigpipes_received = 0;
void enmx_close( ENMX_HANDLE conn )
{
    sConnectionInfo         **connInfo, *temp;
    SOCKET_CMD_HEAD         cmd_head;
    time_t           secs;
    pth_event_t             ev_wakeup;

    temp = NULL;
    for( connInfo = &enmx_connections; *connInfo != NULL; connInfo = &(*connInfo)->next ) {
        if( (*connInfo)->socket == conn ) {
            temp = *connInfo;
            *connInfo = (*connInfo)->next;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( temp != NULL ) {
        cmd_head.cmd = SOCKET_CMD_EXIT;
        cmd_head.address = 0xffff;
        secs = time( NULL ) + TIMEOUT;
        switch( temp->mode ) {
            case ENMX_MODE_STANDARD:
               while( write( conn, &cmd_head, sizeof( cmd_head )) == -1 )
                {
                    if( errno == EAGAIN ) {
                        if( secs <= time( NULL )) {
                            break;
                        }
                        usleep( 10 * 1000 );
                        continue;
                    }
                    /* BAE : if we encounter a sigpipe, the client stupidly continues to try to write to scoket, which never ends...*/
                    else if (errno == EPIPE)
                    {
                       BAE_nb_sigpipes_received++;
                       break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case ENMX_MODE_PTH:
                ev_wakeup = pth_event( PTH_EVENT_TIME, pth_time( secs, 0 ));
                pth_write_ev( conn, &cmd_head, sizeof( cmd_head ), ev_wakeup );
                // either the request has been sent or timeout reached
                // in any case, we've finished
                pth_event_free( ev_wakeup, PTH_FREE_ALL );
                break;
        }
        if( temp->hostname ) free( temp->hostname );
        if( temp->name ) free( temp->name );
        free( temp );
    }

    close( conn );
}
```

`

And here is the code that opens it:
`

```
    if( connect( sock_con, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in )) != 0 ) {
       printf("ENMX_E_SERVER_NOTRUNNING (%s)\n", myname);
       return( ENMX_E_SERVER_NOTRUNNING );
    }
```

`

The code that kills the child process is the following:
`

```
wxProcess::Kill(eibnetmux_process_pid, wxSIGKILL);
```

`

Comment: Please show the code. Programming is a precise activity and we cannot debug with imprecise prose descriptions of code.

Comment: extract of code that generates the sigpipe :`while( write( conn, &cmd_head, sizeof( cmd_head )) == -1 )
 {
     if (errno == EPIPE)
     {
        BAE_nb_sigpipes_received++;
        break;
     }
 }`. After the sigpipe, the socket is closed : `close( conn );`

Comment: extract of code that closes the client process (uses wxWidgets lib...) : `wxProcess::Kill(eibnetmux_process_pid, wxSIGKILL);`

Comment: code that tries to re-open the connection (and that fails...): `if( connect( sock_con, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in )) != 0 ) {
               printf("ENMX_E_SERVER_NOTRUNNING (%s)\n", myname);
               return( ENMX_E_SERVER_NOTRUNNING );
            }`

Comment: Please stop. Don't put code in the comments. All relevant info needs to be in the question body. And code in comments is unreadable. Put it into the question as an [mcve] by clicking the "edit" link under the question.

Comment: When connect command stops working, variable `BAE_nb_sigpipes_received` value is always 10

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with this site. I edited the question and put the code there